# Find resource attached with Azure network interface

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

How can I find the resource attached with an azure network interface using azure powershell or CLI?

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it. If no, give the response.

Comment: Thanks Charles... could we also find the NIC resource attached for other resources, for example an API M instance ??

Comment: I'm afraid not. API M does not need to associate with NIC.

Comment: Do you solve the problem? Please let me know it.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the network interface is only attached to the VM or not. So if you want to get the resources attached with the network interfaces, it means you want to find the VMs, then you can use the Azure CLI like this:

From the network interfaces:

```
az network nic list --query [].virtualMachine.id
```

Directly from the VM (all the VMs attached with the network interface):

```
az vm list
```

If you want to find the VMs in the resource group, then you can add the parameter `--resource-group`.